# Does the iPod Touch 5th Generation have a magnetometer sensor?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

The title says it all: I wonder, does the 5th iPod Touch generation have a magnetometer? There was an Availability matrix for iOS devices up to iPhone 4 / iPad 2 / iPod touch 4G — The 4G didn't have a magnetometer sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPod touch (5th Generation) does not have a magnetometer (digital compass) sensor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is table about which device has which [sensor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html).

Look to magnetometer compatibility.

So sensor is absent on iphone + iphone 3g + any iPod including iPod 6 gen.